# Emulating class extending

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using the following piece of JavaScript to emulate class extending. Is this a valid way to go or does it have some drawbacks which should definitely be fixed?

```
var Validator = function (inputId) {
    "use strict";

    var self = this;

    self.inputId = inputId;

    window.document.getElementById(inputId).onblur = function () {
        self.check();
    };

};

Validator.prototype.inputId = '';

/**
 * Validator fails by default
 *  
 * @returns {Boolean} 
 */
Validator.prototype.isValid = function () {
    "use strict";

    return false;

};

/**
 * Check whether the input is valid
 * 
 * @returns {Validator}
 */
Validator.prototype.check = function () {
    "use strict";

    // Check and mark whether validation passes
    if (!this.isValid()) {

        this.markInvalid();

    } else {

        this.markValid();

    }

    return this;

};

/**
 * Mark the input as valid
 * 
 * @returns {Validator}
 */
Validator.prototype.markValid = function () {
    "use strict";

    var input = window.document.getElementById(this.inputId);

    // Remove "error" class name
    input.className = input.className.replace(
        /(?:^|\s)error(?!\S)/g,
        ''
    );

    return this;

};

/**
 * Mark input as invalid
 * 
 * @returns {Validator}
 */
Validator.prototype.markInvalid = function () {
    "use strict";

    var input = window.document.getElementById(this.inputId);

    // Add "error" class when it is not set already
    if (!input.className.match(/(?:^|\s)error(?!\S)/g)) {
        input.className += ' error';
    }

    return this;

};
```

Than this is used as a concrete validator implementation

```
// Inherit from validator
var VatCheck = Validator;

/**
 * Validate vat number
 * 
 * @note only format is checked, not whether the number is in use
 * 
 * @returns {Boolean} 
 */
VatCheck.prototype.isValid = function () {
    "use strict";

    var input = window.document.getElementById(this.inputId);

    // Check number by using Vat.js
    return !!checkVATNumber(input.value);

};
```

The reason I came to this solution is because only one or two methods of the parent class have different behavior, and the use of the strategy pattern seems somewhat over-engineering

Comment: This looks like example code... are you just toying around or are you planning an implementation of this?

Comment: @Pimgd I'm working on an implementation of a form validator. Just removed the function implementation to be able to review the structure and make the example clearer. Code reviewing a technique or structure does not need to be production code is it?

Comment: Sorry, real code only. Right now, we cannot provide you with a contextual answer. That means we're limited to the bits of code you've provided - for which the solution would probably work well enough. Then you use that everywhere where you need inheritance and due to some oversight, you've just created a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: It's not a bad question, it's just that right now, there's a high chance of you getting inappropriate advice which you will use to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing is example code rather than code that you're actually using in a real project, which means that a lot of context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. Please see the meta question: [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question when I get back at my laptop :)

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) - in this case, I suggest taking your code and sorting out the issues that have been pointed out, and then re-posting it as a new question here on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one bad problem in the code that can be answered by the basis of the pattern presented here:

```
// Inherit from validator
var VatCheck = Validator;
```

This does not inherit anything, instead it causes `VatCheck` name to point to the exact same object (constructor function) as the `Validator`. Thus all you are doing is overwriting `Validator.prototype.isValid` (changing the base implementation), and aliasing the base implementation by different names.

If you repeat this pattern again, the end result is that all validators have their `isValid` check method do the action of the **last validator type that you define**.

Instead you need to do `VatCheck.prototype = new Validator()` but then you need to also redo the constructor.

Comment: Ok, makes a lot of sense. I'll modify the inheriting class and move the constructor logic to a separate initialization function.